# whois query doesn't work

Tags: bash, whois

Today I encountered a problem with jwhois.

The problem is that it doesn't respond at all. It just queries
the given or predefined host and gives no other output after
this. Here are a few examples:

```
18:39:22 schwarz@f455-5:~ $>whois google.com
[Querying whois.denic.de]
^C
18:39:58 schwarz@f455-5:~ $>whois -h whois.denic.de -- "-T dn google.com"
[Querying whois.denic.de]
^C
18:51:21 schwarz@f455-5:~ $>whois -h whois.webhosting.info google.com
[Querying whois.webhosting.info]
[Unable to connect to remote host]
18:54:58 schwarz@f455-5:~ $>whois -h whois.internic.net google.com
[Querying whois.internic.net]
```

As you can see, I also tried a few other hosts I found online, but it didn't work at all. Might be useful to know: I'm sitting in the facility of a university, though I have no influence on the firewall or everything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be blocked in your universities firewall, whois uses port 43 TCP by default.

Unless you can find a whois server that uses port 80 (depending on the firewall it may even block that) it might be best to use a web based whois service such as http://who.is/.

Perhaps test with another computer somewhere, if you can use telnet run:

```
deb:~# telnet whois.denic.de 43
Trying 81.91.170.6...
Connected to whois.denic.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
% Error: 55000000007 Request not clearly specified
```

Comment: Okay, i tried around a bit and it seems, that Port 43 is blocked by the network security. I got it to work via a different host, -p 80 and then using grep to get the required information.
But it's much easier via browser.